# Check if a text box have a "tip" value or not with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms

My search form uses a "tip" on the text box, which when onfocus it clear the text box and on blur it shows the "tip".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkform(form)
{
  if (search.s.value == "Pesquisar...") || (search.s.value == "") {
    var term = prompt("Enter a value:");
    if (term) { search.s.value = term; }
    else { return false; }
  }
}
</script>

<form id="search" method="get" action="[@siteurl]/search.php" onsubmit="return checkform(this);" >
  <fieldset>
    <input type="text" name="s" value="Pesquisar..." onfocus="if(this.value=='Pesquisar...') { this.value=''; }" onblur="if(this.value=='') { this.value='Pesquisar...'; }"  /> 
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Go!" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

This is not working. It is searching the tip text instead of the prompt.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function checkform(form)
{
   if (search.s.value == "Pesquisar..." || search.s.value == "")//brackets not closed properly 
   {
      var term = prompt("Enter a value:");
      if (term) { search.s.value = term; }
      else { return false; }
   }
}
```

check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NmJ7H/)